# Independent scopes for similar controllers in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm working on an app the uses multiple (but similar) controllers (`controllerA`) on a page and another controller (`controllerB`) that could change some properties, but ONLY if the element of `controllerA` was previously selected.

(in `controllerA` some properties could have default values, that are passed and applied by using data- attributes)

In this stage, I can only modify the last color property with `controllerB` (which makes sense, because that's the active scope. My question is, how can I change controllerB scope to be the "active" scope-copy  of the selected `controllerA`?

```
// Code goes here

var webApp = angular.module("webApp", []);

webApp.controller("controllerA", function($scope, $rootScope, $element, styleFactory){
$scope.selected = false;
var color = angular.element($element[0]).attr("data-style-color");
styleFactory.setColor(color);  
$scope.data = styleFactory.getData();

$scope.select = function(){
  $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;
}
});

webApp.controller("controllerB", function($scope, $rootScope, $element, styleFactory){
  $scope.data = styleFactory.getData();
});

webApp.factory("styleFactory", function(){
  var data = {"style":"color:yellow"}

  return {
    setColor: function(color){
      data = {"style":"color:"+color};
    },
    getData: function(){
      return data;
    }
  };
});
```

for full example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/He2m7ArfRSur9Igq2eur?p=preview

thanks,
--iM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see a modified plnkr that works as you described [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/805aPWmRtLoaOchpmNTU?p=preview).

Personally, I would restructure the architecture of the app and rethink the styleFactory implementation.

Some points for thought:

- `data = {"style":"color:"+color}` replaces the whole data object, thus `$scope.data = styleFactory.getData()` works only for the last `controllerA` as the reference is lost for all others.
- Try creating a parent controller that will be on top of `controllerA` and `controllerB`.
- Try solving this problem using directives.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I actually have another [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/e52LtYBRhyXC7M4nhxd1?p=preview) where I was trying to do the same thing with one controller and multiple directives. The issue is that my controller is outside of the directives (not wrapping them around), but that might be the only way to make this work... thx again